# How to group by two tables with CTE

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, common-table-expression

I have three tables (Oracle):

```
sales_order
-------------
int so_key (pk)
int part_key (fk)
int condition_key (fk)
number unit_price
int qty_ordered
number unit_cost
date entry_date

quote
-------------
int q_key (pk) 
int part_key (fk)
int condition_key (fk)
number unit_price
int qty_quoted
date entry_date

stock
-------------
int stock_key (pk)
int part_key (fk)
int condition (fk)
int qty_available
number unit_cost
```

And all three have foreign key references to these two tables:

```
part
-------------
int part_key (pk) 

condition
-------------
int condition_key (pk)
```

I am writing a query that will aggregate the data into rows grouped by `part` and `condition`. However, I am unable to figure out how to group by BOTH `part` and `condition`. Here is the (functional) query that I have that groups by `part` only:

```
WITH
    ctePart_Quotes AS
    (
        SELECT q.part_key
            , COUNT(*) AS quotes_count
            , SUM(q.unit_price * q.qty_quoted) AS quotes_amt_total
            , SUM(q.qty_quoted) AS quotes_qty_total
        FROM quote q
        WHERE q.entry_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-Jan-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy') AND TO_DATE('31-Dec-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
        GROUP BY q.part_key
    )
    , ctePart_Sales AS
    (
        SELECT so.part_key
            , COUNT(*) AS sales_count
            , SUM(so.unit_price * so.qty_ordered) AS sales_amt_total
            , SUM(so.qty_ordered) AS sales_qty_total
            , SUM(so.qty_ordered * so.unit_cost) AS cost_total
        FROM sales_order so
        WHERE so.entry_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-Jan-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy') AND TO_DATE('31-Dec-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
        GROUP BY so.part_key
    )
    , ctePart_Stock AS
    (
        SELECT stm.part_key
            , SUM(stm.qty_available) AS total_available
            , SUM(stm.qty_available * stm.unit_cost) AS inv_cost
        FROM stock stm
        GROUP BY stm.part_key
    )
SELECT p.part_key,
        part_stock.total_available,
        part_stock.inv_cost,
        sales.sales_amt_total,
        sales.sales_qty_total,
        sales.sales_count,
        sales.cost_total,
        quotes.quotes_amt_total,
        quotes.quotes_qty_total,
        quotes.quotes_count
  FROM parts p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ctePart_Quotes quotes
    ON quotes.part_key = p.part_key
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ctePart_Sales sales
    ON sales.part_key = p.part_key
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ctePart_Stock part_stock
    ON part_stock.part_key = p.part_key

WHERE NOT(sales_amt_total IS NULL
        AND sales_qty_total IS NULL
        AND sales_count IS NULL
        AND cost_total IS NULL
        AND quotes_amt_total IS NULL
        AND quotes_qty_total IS NULL
        AND quotes_count IS NULL)
    AND SALES_AMT_TOTAL > 10000
```

This query produces this output (totals grouped by part_key):

```
part_key | total_available | inv_cost | sales_amt_total | ...
---------|-----------------|----------|-----------------| ...
     234 |              59 |  4923.90 |        29403.48 | ...
     185 |              21 |   192.64 |         9034.95 | ...
     102 |             102 |  8738.34 |        50382.20 | ...
...
```

But I'm trying to modify the query to produce this (totals grouped by part_key and condition_key):

```
part_key | condition_key | total_available | inv_cost | sales_amt_total | ...
---------|---------------|-----------------|----------|-----------------| ...
     234 |             3 |              24 |  2360.50 |        16947.18 | ...
     234 |             7 |              35 |  2563.40 |        12456.30 | ...
...
```

How do you do this?

EDIT: for clarification:
The complexity lies in: how do you `join` the condition in the final select? Because you are selecting `FROM part` but the `condition` relationship is through the other tables (sales_order, etc.). So you'd have to `join` through each of the tables (`LEFT OUTER JOIN condition cond ON quotes.condition_key = cond.condition_key`, etc.) but those joins would each be separate columns.

EDIT #2: someone provided a good image of the data model that illustrates the (proper, legitimate) relationship between part/condition but also the subtle complexity faced in this problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to first create a Carthesian product (The `condition` table only has ~30 rows), and *maybe* suppress the unwanted result rows later:

This may look sub-optimal, but it will avoid a join on`COALESCE()`d keyfields, which could perform badly.

---

```
WITH
    ctePart_Quotes AS
    (
        SELECT q.part_key, q.condition_key
            , COUNT(*) AS quotes_count
            , SUM(q.unit_price * q.qty_quoted) AS quotes_amt_total
            , SUM(q.qty_quoted) AS quotes_qty_total
        FROM quote q
        WHERE q.entry_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-Jan-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy') AND TO_DATE('31-Dec-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
        GROUP BY q.part_key, q.condition_key
    )
    , ctePart_Sales AS
    (
        SELECT so.part_key, so.condition_key
            , COUNT(*) AS sales_count
            , SUM(so.unit_price * so.qty_ordered) AS sales_amt_total
            , SUM(so.qty_ordered) AS sales_qty_total
            , SUM(so.qty_ordered * so.unit_cost) AS cost_total
        FROM sales_order so
        WHERE so.entry_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-Jan-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy') AND TO_DATE('31-Dec-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
        GROUP BY so.part_key, so.condition_key
    )
    , ctePart_Stock AS
    (
        SELECT stm.part_key, stm.condition_key
            , SUM(stm.qty_available) AS total_available
            , SUM(stm.qty_available * stm.unit_cost) AS inv_cost
        FROM stock stm
        GROUP BY stm.part_key, stm.condition_key
    )

SELECT p.part_key,
       c.condition_key,
        part_stock.total_available,
        part_stock.inv_cost,
        sales.sales_amt_total,
        sales.sales_qty_total,
        sales.sales_count,
        sales.cost_total,
        quotes.quotes_amt_total,
        quotes.quotes_qty_total,
        quotes.quotes_count
  FROM parts p
  CROSS JOIN condition c -- <<-- Here
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ctePart_Quotes quotes
    ON quotes.part_key = p.part_key
    AND quotes.condition_key = c.condition_key -- <<-- Here
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ctePart_Sales sales
    ON sales.part_key = p.part_key
    AND sales.condition_key = c.condition_key -- <<-- Here
  LEFT OUTER JOIN ctePart_Stock part_stock
    ON part_stock.part_key = p.part_key
    AND part_stock.condition_key = c.condition_key -- <<-- Here

WHERE NOT(sales_amt_total IS NULL
        AND sales_qty_total IS NULL
        AND sales_count IS NULL
        AND cost_total IS NULL
        AND quotes_amt_total IS NULL
        AND quotes_qty_total IS NULL
        AND quotes_count IS NULL) -- <<-- And maybe Here, too
    AND SALES_AMT_TOTAL > 10000
    ;
```

Comment: I'm testing this right now and it appears to be working splendidly. Is there a performance hit with `cross join` that I should know about when the data scales?

Comment: I don't know Oracle well enough. All the joins are on keyfields, so I *expect* it to pick a reasonable plan. (does Oracle have Hash-joins?)

Comment: IDK. Anyways, I'm surprised no one mentioned `CROSS JOIN` as the answer because it seems so obvious

Answer (score 2):

The main problem here seems to be your data model.  Converting the table "descriptions" of your question into DDL code, and reversing this to a relational model (using Oracle Datamodeler), we find something like this:

**DDL code**

```
create table part ( part_key number primary key ) ;
create table condition ( condition_key number primary key ) ;

create table sales_order (
  so_key number generated always as identity start with 3000 primary key 
, part_key number references part 
, condition_key number references condition
, unit_price number
, qty_ordered number
, unit_cost number
, entry_date date ) ;

create table quote (
  q_key number generated always as identity start with 4000  primary key
, part_key number references part
, condition_key number references condition
, qty_quoted number
, unit_price number
, entry_date date );

create table stock (
  stock_key number generated always as identity start with 5000  primary key
, part_key number references part
, condition_key number references condition
, qty_available number 
, unit_cost number ) ;
```

**Relational model (Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler)**

[image]

Looking at the model, it becomes clear that each PART can have several CONDITIONs.  Thus, it may be necessary (for you) to decide, which condition you are referring to.  That may not be easy.  Suppose we have a part (with part_key) 1000.  Now, we can record 3 different conditions, and use a specific condition for each of your 3 tables mentioned in your query.

```
-- one part, 3 conditions
begin
  insert into part ( part_key ) values ( 1000 ) ;
  insert into condition( condition_key ) values ( 2001 ) ;
  insert into condition( condition_key ) values ( 2002 ) ;
  insert into condition( condition_key ) values ( 2003 ) ;
  insert into sales_order ( part_key, condition_key ) values ( 1000, 2001 ) ;
  insert into quote ( part_key, condition_key ) values ( 1000, 2002 ) ;
  insert into stock ( part_key, condition_key ) values ( 1000, 2003 ) ;
end ;
/
```

Which one of the 3 condition is supposed to be used for the query? Hard to tell.

```
-- not using WITH (subquery factoring) here - for clarity 
select
  P.part_key
, SO.condition_key
, Q.condition_key
, ST.condition_key
from part P
  join sales_order SO on SO.part_key = P.part_key 
  join quote Q        on Q.part_key  = P.part_key 
  join stock ST       on ST.part_key = P.part_key 
;

-- output
PART_KEY  CONDITION_KEY  CONDITION_KEY  CONDITION_KEY  
1000      2001           2002           2003
```

Well - we could pick one of the conditions, couldn't we.  However, even more conditions can exist for one and the same part ...

```
begin
  insert into condition( condition_key ) values ( 2004 ) ;
  insert into condition( condition_key ) values ( 2005 ) ;
  insert into condition( condition_key ) values ( 2006 ) ;
  insert into sales_order ( part_key, condition_key ) values ( 1000, 2004 ) ;
  insert into quote ( part_key, condition_key ) values ( 1000, 2005 ) ;
  insert into stock ( part_key, condition_key ) values ( 1000, 2006 ) ;
end ;
/

-- Same query as above now gives us:
PART_KEY  CONDITION_KEY  CONDITION_KEY  CONDITION_KEY  
1000      2001           2005           2006           
1000      2001           2005           2003           
1000      2001           2002           2006           
1000      2001           2002           2003           
1000      2004           2005           2006           
1000      2004           2005           2003           
1000      2004           2002           2006           
1000      2004           2002           2003
```

Conclusion: Fix your data model. (We know this is sometimes easier said than done ...)  Then, it will make sense to do some more work on your query.

**__Update__**

Now that we know that nothing can be done about the tables and the constraints, maybe the following queries will give you a starting point.  We do not have proper test data, so let's just add some random values to the tables ...

```
-- PART and CONDITION -> 1000 integers each
begin
  for i in 1 .. 1000
  loop
    insert into part ( part_key ) values ( i ) ;
    insert into condition( condition_key ) values ( i ) ;
  end loop;
end ;
/
```

**Table QUOTE**

```
-- 2 12s, 2 18s
SQL> select * from quote ;
Q_KEY  PART_KEY  CONDITION_KEY  QTY_QUOTED  UNIT_PRICE  ENTRY_DATE  
4000   10        100            55          500         01-MAY-11   
4001   12        120            55          500         01-MAY-11   
4002   12        37             56          501         01-MAY-11   
4003   14        140            55          500         01-MAY-11   
4004   15        46             56          501         01-MAY-11   
4005   16        160            55          500         01-MAY-11   
4006   18        180            55          500         01-MAY-11   
4007   18        55             56          501         01-MAY-11   
4008   20        200            55          500         01-MAY-11
```

**Table SALES_ORDER**

```
SQL> select * from sales_order ;

SO_KEY  PART_KEY  CONDITION_KEY  UNIT_PRICE  QTY_ORDERED  UNIT_COST  ENTRY_DATE  
3000    10        100            500         55           400        05-MAY-11   
3001    12        120            500         55           400        05-MAY-11   
3002    14        140            500         55           400        05-MAY-11   
3003    16        160            500         55           400        05-MAY-11   
3004    18        180            500         55           400        05-MAY-11   
3005    20        200            500         55           400        05-MAY-11
```

**Table STOCK**

```
SQL> select * from stock ;
STOCK_KEY  PART_KEY  CONDITION_KEY  QTY_AVAILABLE  UNIT_COST  
5000       10        100            10             400        
5001       12        120            10             400        
5002       14        140            10             400        
5003       14        100            12             402        
5004       16        160            10             400        
5005       18        180            10             400        
5006       20        200            10             400
```

Assuming that only valid part/condition combinations are recorded, we can use FULL OUTER JOINs to get a first picture.

```
SQL> select 
  2    Q.part_key  q_part , Q.condition_key  q_cond
  3  , SO.part_key so_part, SO.condition_key so_cond
  4  , ST.part_key st_part, ST.condition_key st_cond
  5  from quote Q 
  6    full join sales_order SO
  7      on SO.part_key = Q.part_key and SO.condition_key = Q.condition_key
  8    full join stock ST  
  9      on ST.part_key = SO.part_key and ST.condition_key = SO.condition_key
 10  ;

-- result
Q_PART  Q_COND  SO_PART  SO_COND  ST_PART  ST_COND  
10      100     10       100      10       100      
12      120     12       120      12       120      
12      37      NULL     NULL     NULL     NULL     
14      140     14       140      14       140      
15      46      NULL     NULL     NULL     NULL     
16      160     16       160      16       160      
18      180     18       180      18       180      
18      55      NULL     NULL     NULL     NULL     
20      200     20       200      20       200      
NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL     14       100
```

Then, we can use Analytic Functions for the various calculations.  Note that we do not use GROUP BY here, the grouping is done via ... partition by Q.part_key, Q.condition_key ... (More about analytic functions: Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174), and examples [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/analytic-functions)).

```
-- Skeleton query ...
-- Note that you will have need to write over(...) several times.
-- Add a WHERE clause and conditions as required.
select
  Q.part_key as q_part, Q.condition_key as q_cond, 
  count( Q.part_key ) over ( partition by Q.part_key, Q.condition_key ) as q_count
-- 
-- Q example sums
-- , sum( Q.unit_price * Q.qty_quoted ) 
--     over ( partition by Q.part_key, Q.condition_key ) as qat -- quotes_amt_total
-- , sum( Q.qty_quoted ) 
--    over ( partition by Q.part_key, Q.condition_key ) as qqt -- quotes_qty_total
-- 
, SO.part_key as so_part, SO.condition_key as so_cond
, count( SO.part_key ) over ( partition by SO.part_key, SO.condition_key ) as so_count
-- 
-- SO sums here
--
, ST.part_key as st_part, ST.condition_key as st_cond
, count( ST.part_key ) over ( partition by ST.part_key, ST.condition_key ) as st_count
from sales_order SO 
  full join quote Q  
    on SO.part_key = Q.part_key and SO.condition_key = Q.condition_key
  full join stock ST  
    on ST.part_key = SO.part_key and ST.condition_key = SO.condition_key
-- where ...
;
```

**Result**

```
-- output
Q_PART  Q_COND  Q_COUNT  SO_PART  SO_COND  SO_COUNT  ST_PART  ST_COND  ST_COUNT  
10      100     1        10       100      1         10       100      1         
12      37      1        NULL     NULL     0         NULL     NULL     0         
12      120     1        12       120      1         12       120      1         
14      140     1        14       140      1         14       140      1         
15      46      1        NULL     NULL     0         NULL     NULL     0         
16      160     1        16       160      1         16       160      1         
18      55      1        NULL     NULL     0         NULL     NULL     0         
18      180     1        18       180      1         18       180      1         
20      200     1        20       200      1         20       200      1         
NULL    NULL    0        NULL     NULL     0         14       100      1
```

Comment: The data model is not editable. It’s a prepackaged software (not mine). I am just a third party writing reports for it. Your assessment of the relationship between part/condition is exactly right (“each part can have several conditions”). But this relationship between part/condition is perfectly legitimate (another reason why the model doesn’t need to be “fixed”).

Comment: “Which one of the conditions is supposed to be used for the query” — the entire purpose of the query is to return a list of ALL the parts by ALL the conditions (unless that part/condition pairing isn’t used in any of the transaction tables)

Comment: It should be noted that the "condition" table only has about 30 rows. Imagine that instead of "condition" it were "color." How would you show the data per part per color?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback!  I would probably not bother with subquery factoring (CTEs), but use analytic functions instead - see the "update", attached to my original answer.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you:

```
WITH
    ctePart_Quotes AS
    (
        SELECT q.part_key,
               q.condition_key
            , COUNT(*) AS quotes_count
            , SUM(q.unit_price * q.qty_quoted) AS quotes_amt_total
            , SUM(q.qty_quoted) AS quotes_qty_total
        FROM quote q
        WHERE q.entry_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-Jan-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy') AND TO_DATE('31-Dec-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
        GROUP BY q.part_key,
                 q.condition_key
    )
    , ctePart_Sales AS
    (
        SELECT so.part_key,
               so.condition_key
            , COUNT(*) AS sales_count
            , SUM(so.unit_price * so.qty_ordered) AS sales_amt_total
            , SUM(so.qty_ordered) AS sales_qty_total
            , SUM(so.qty_ordered * so.unit_cost) AS cost_total
        FROM sales_order so
        WHERE so.entry_date BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-Jan-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy') AND TO_DATE('31-Dec-2011', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
        GROUP BY so.part_key,
                 so.condition_key
    )
    , ctePart_Stock AS
    (
        SELECT stm.part_key,
               stm.condition_key
            , SUM(stm.qty_available) AS total_available
            , SUM(stm.qty_available * stm.unit_cost) AS inv_cost
        FROM stock stm
        GROUP BY stm.part_key,
                 stm.condition_key
    )
SELECT p.part_key,
        cte.condition_key,
        cte.total_available,
        cte.inv_cost,
        cte.sales_amt_total,
        cte.sales_qty_total,
        cte.sales_count,
        cte.cost_total,
        cte.quotes_amt_total,
        cte.quotes_qty_total,
        cte.quotes_count
  FROM parts p
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT coalesce(quotes.part_key, sales.part_key, part_stock.part_key) part_key,
                          coalesce(quotes.condition_key, sales.condition_key, part_stock.condition_key) condition_key,
                          quotes.quotes_count,
                          quotes.quotes_amt_total,
                          quotes.quotes_qty_total,
                          sales.sales_count,
                          sales.sales_amt_total,
                          sales.sales_qty_total,
                          sales.cost_total,
                          part_stock.total_available,
                          part_stock.inv_cost
                          FROM ctePart_Quotes quotes
                               FULL JOIN ctePart_Sales sales
                                         ON sales.part_key = quotes.part_key
                                            AND sales.condition_key = quotes.condition_key
                               FULL JOIN ctePart_Stock part_stock
                                         ON part_stock.part_key = sales.part_key
                                            AND part_stock.condition_key = sales.condition_key) cte
    ON cte.part_key = p.part_key
WHERE NOT(sales_amt_total IS NULL
        AND cte.sales_qty_total IS NULL
        AND cte.sales_count IS NULL
        AND cte.cost_total IS NULL
        AND cte.quotes_amt_total IS NULL
        AND cte.quotes_qty_total IS NULL
        AND cte.quotes_count IS NULL)
    AND SALES_AMT_TOTAL > 10000;
```

It also groups by `condition_key` in the CTEs. Then it `FULL JOIN`s the CTEs together using `coalesce` to compensate for `null` values of `part_key` or `condition_key` in the first tables (But maybe there is none, if every combination of `part_key`and `condition_key`, that is present in one of the tables is also present in the respective two other tables.). The result is then `LEFT JOIN`ed to `part` using `part_key`.